# How to obtain a unicode character from a QString?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

so hopefully this is simpler than I'm making it out to be.  I'm reading JSON data into my application, and an entry emerges as the QString `"\uf103"`, which actually is represented by the characters `'\\'`, `'u'`, `'f'`, `'1'`, `'0'`, and `'3'`. How would I actually convert this to a unicode character represented by the code `\uf103`?  I've gone through a number of threads that seem to ask similar questions, but none of them have a straightforward answer.

For context, I'm just trying to display this character as the text of a button.

My parsing routine looks like this:

```
    QString infoPath = QDir::currentPath() + "/resources/fonts/fontawesome/unicode_info.json";
    QJsonObject fontAwesome = JsonReader(infoPath).getContentsAsJsonObject();

    QString fa = JsonReader::getJsonValueAsQString(fontAwesome);
    if (!fontAwesome.contains(fontAwesomeIcon)) {
        qDebug() << "Error, font awesome icon not found";
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
        throw("Error, font awesome icon not found");
#endif
    }
    QString unicode = fontAwesome.value(fontAwesomeIcon).toObject().value("unicode").toString();
```

The string `unicode` is the subjects of interest.  The original JSON looks like this, just larger:

```
{"500px": {"unicode": "\\uf26e", "styles": ["brands"], "label": "500px"}, "accessible-icon": {"unicode": "\\uf368", "styles": ["brands"], "label": "Accessible Icon"}, "accusoft": {"unicode": "\\uf369", "styles": ["brands"], "label": "Accusoft"}, "acquisitions-incorporated": {"unicode": "\\uf6af", "styles": ["brands"], "label": "Acquisitions Incorporated"}}
```

So, the problem is that I'm starting with double slashes in the first place. I'm open to a method of pre-processing this JSON in python as well, if there is a way to get unicode characters that way.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc An example of what?  I don't know how to approach solving this problem.  You want me to show you how I got a string with six characters in it?

Comment: No, I will be more precise, as you point out that you use a json, I suspect that the problem is in the json parser, so it would be great if you share the JSON file (or a link where you can download the JSON file) or the method of how you get the JSON.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, didn't mean to be snarky.  Hopefully the example I've added helps.

Comment: I think you did not understand me, seeing the 2 "\" makes me think that this print is using C++ so the string is already lost. Could you upload the unicode_info.json to an online service like drive, dropbox, etc and share the link?

Comment: @eyllanesc Sure, here you go https://file.io/gwrsSW

Comment: @Danny that link reports a "404 page not found" error .  But in the JSON you showed, the `unicode` value is malformed. If it were a proper encoded Unicode string then `"\\uf26e"` would be `"\uf26e"` instead per the JSON spec, and a compliant JSON parser would decode it manually for you. As-is, you will have to decode it manually instead.

Comment: *the problem is that I'm starting with double slashes in the first place* -- Then get a hold of whoever produced that string and let them know it is not valid.

Comment: @Danny I agree with the previous comments. How did you create the .json? On the other hand the link is broken.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, here's a new link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7eucdwlkadjyxkm/unicode_info.json?dl=0 .  This is the only file I have.  Is it possible to modify it somehow to suit my needs?

Comment: @Danny mmm, the repair can generate other problems. How did you generate the json?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the codepoints you are trying are not specified in Unicode.  Yes they are feasible hex values for codepoints, there is a big gap between f000 and f900,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a python processing step, running the following line on every problematic string:

```
problem_string = "\\u2095"
good_string = bytes(problem_string, "ascii").decode('unicode-escape'),
```